# Yii2 - Gii Model Relations - Why is there a 0 after the function names?

Tags: php, yii2, gii

I haven't seen this online when looking at other's code, guides, tutorials, etc.

When I generate a Model with Gii, the functions regarding relations all have a zero after them.

---

**Example:**

```
class Benefit extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    // truncated Yii Model code...

    public function getType0()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(BenefitTypes::className(), ['id' => 'type']);
    }
}
```

---

BenefitTypes is an id to name mapping:

```
id | name
---------------
1  =>  Federal
2  =>  Non-Profit
```

In the 'benefit' table, it has column named 'type' that is a relation to the 'benefit_types' table 'id' column.

I though I should be able to do (in /views/benefit/index.php) 'type.name' but it doesn't work either. It changes the column name to "Type Name" and puts "(not set)" in the data table...

Example:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'id',
        'somevalue',
        'type.name',
    ],
]) ?>
```

What is going on, why does it not act like it's supposed to?

---

## UPDATE

I am beginning to think the 0 suffix to the relation function names, ie: getType0, is due to "type" being used in the table as a column name to avoid duplication or confusion. I can't find this documented though, so would like to have a definite answer on that.

I changed the function name to getTypeRelation(). Then in the index.php view, for the detailview widget, used 'typeRelation.name' and it returned the name through the relation just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thinking is correct. Generation of the relation names is done by the function [generateRelationName()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-gii/blob/master/generators/model/Generator.php#L497).

```
protected function generateRelationName($relations, $table, $key, $multiple)
{
    if (!empty($key) && substr_compare($key, 'id', -2, 2, true) === 0 && strcasecmp($key, 'id')) {
        $key = rtrim(substr($key, 0, -2), '_');
    }
    if ($multiple) {
        $key = Inflector::pluralize($key);
    }
    $name = $rawName = Inflector::id2camel($key, '_');
    $i = 0;
    while (isset($table->columns[lcfirst($name)])) {
        $name = $rawName . ($i++);
    }
    while (isset($relations[$table->fullName][$name])) {
        $name = $rawName . ($i++);
    }
    return $name;
}
```

Yii uses the related table's name as the relation name. Should you have a column with the same name as the related table, a digit will be appended to the relation to avoid confusion due to Yii's handling of magic functions. This also occurs if you have two columns or more in a single table related to the same table e.g columns `create_user_id`, `update_user_id` and `delete_user_id` related to table `user` will result in relations named `user`, `user0` and `user1`.

For your example, it is advisable to name your foreign key field something else e.g `type_id` or `typeId`. Yii will handle these correctly . The other alternative when you have multiple columns related to the same table is to just rename the functions.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer. I was in the source on GitHub and found the function you were talking about, and figured that was the gist of it. Now, this does not only happen to "type", it was happening to other columns and resulted in 'getCategory0' and 'getBenefit0' which are not Yii functions or variables, just the names of my columns. I changed them to like 'getCategoryRelation' and use them respectively, without any issues. I think adding Relation to the end makes better code as I know what it really is.

Answer (score 0):

Because relational column name and the relation name is same. When you call `$benefit->type` what you will expect, the value of the column/property `type` or the instance of `BenefitTypes`? So now you know. `$benefit->type` return the property value and `$benefit->type0` returns the instance of relation.